# Lambda expression producing a SyntaxError

Tags: python, string, lambda

I am looking for an lambda expression to print an integer if a given string is in a given sentence separated by `/`. This is the statement I wrote:

```
hunter = udf(lambda x : 'opened' in x.lower().split() print(10) elif 'clickedurl' in x.lower().split() print(20)  else print("null"))
s= it/is/opened/memory/tae
hunter(s)
```

I am getting the following error

```
 File "/home/main.py", line 1                                                                                         
    hunter = udf(lambda x : 'opened' in x.lower().split() print(10) elif 'clickedurl' in x.lower().split() print 20  el
se print("null"))                                                                                                      
                                                              ^                                                        
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Can you format your question properly using code blocks?
Others want to help, can you make it easier for them?

Comment: I suggest you write your code out in the conventional if-elif-else blocks over multiple lines, and use `def` if you need a named function

Comment: I believe the `elif` statement is invalid in a one-line expression like that. I guess you want to use a ternary "operator", so try expanding `elif` into `else if`.

Comment: The basic problem is that your lamba expression is *not* an expression: you have tried to include a `print` statement, then an `elif` without any attached `if` or `else`.

Comment: Thank you all for the help This is my first posting on stack overflow an I haven't expected this friendly and quick response from all thank you very much my fellow Pythoners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple syntax errors in your code, and you have to fix all of them.

---

First, `lambda` expressions—like all expressions—cannot have statements in them, only expressions.

And that includes Python 2's `print` statement, which you appear to be using.

If you want to write a function that includes a statement, you need to use a `def` statement, not a `lambda` expression.

---

Second, if you were trying to write an `if-else` expression, you got the syntax for that wrong. You need to put the true-expression first, then `if`, then the condition to check, then `else`, then the false-expression.

You appear to have been trying to put the condition first, right before the true-expression:

```
'opened' in x.lower().split() print(10)
```

You can't do that. And that's where your first `SyntaxError`, the one you're asking about, comes from.

---

Third, you cannot use `elif` in an `if-else` expression. You'd have to write it into an `if-else` expression with another `if-else` expression as the false-value.

Which is going to look horrible. If you find yourself needing that, you almost certainly want to break it out into an `if` statement instead.

---

Also, while it isn't *illegal*, it's highly *misleading* to use an `if-else` expression for its side effects.. `if-else` expressions are about picking one value or another, not about running one set of side effects or another. If the latter is what you want, you want an `if` statement.

And the same is true for `lambda`. That's about defining functions that compute values; a function that's only called for its side effects should almost always be a `def`.

---

So, what you want is this:

```
def thingy(x):
    if 'opened' in x.lower().split():
        print(10)
    elif 'clickedurl' in x.lower().split():
        print(20)
    else:
        print('null')

hunter = udf(thingy)
```

And notice that this gives you the opportunity to improve things (both readability and performance) by avoiding some repetition:

```
def thingy(x):
    words = x.lower().split()
    if 'opened' in words:
        print(10)
    elif 'clickedurl' words:
        print(20)
    else:
        print('null')
```

Although of course you don't want to use names like `x` and `thingy`. I have no idea what any of these things represent, but surely you do.

And finally, I don't know what that `udf` function is, but I can't imagine it returning anything useful when called with a function that always returns `None`, so I'll bet you have more problems beyond these, but hopefully you can solve them from here.

---

And of course once you fix all of that, the next line is *also* a syntax error:

```
s= it/is/opened/memory/tae
```

This is attempting to divide a bunch of things. Even if `it`, `opened`, `memory`, and `tae` are all variables with relevant values, `is` certainly isn't, because it's a built-in operator, so you can't divide anything by it.

You probably wanted a string here.

Also, because you're calling `split()` without any argument, that's only going to split things separated by whitespace. So, either you wanted `split('/')` above, or you wanted whitespace here.

So:

```
s = 'it is opened memory tae'
```

---

If you really wanted to make this one giant expression, it's *possible*, but it's going to be very, very ugly.

First, you have to replace that `print` statement with a function call. Of course you could `from __future__ import print_function`, but otherwise, you need to write a function that does what you want, or use one that already exists.

Second, you either need an `if-else` inside an `if-else` as the argument to that function, or you need to call that function in each branch of an `if-else` in an `if-else`. I think the first is slightly less horrible.

So:

```
lambda x: sys.stdout.write(
    str(10 if 'opened' in x.lower().split() else (
             20 if 'clickedurl' in x.lower().split() else 'null'))
    + '\n')
```

And of course inside an expression, whitespace doesn't matter, so you can freely rewrite that to be even uglier if you want:

```
lambda x:sys.stdout.write(str(10 if 'opened' in x.lower().split() else(20 if 'clickedurl' in x.lower().split() else 'null'))+ '\n')
```

… or:

```
lambda x: sys.stdout.write(str
       (10 
  if 'opened' in x.
            lower
           (
         ).
     split() else (20
   if 'clickedurl' in x.lower().split() else 'null'))+ '\n')
```

I can't imagine why you'd want the latter, but then I can't imagine why you'd want the former either, and yet you seemed to be trying to write something as much like that as possible, so… go for it.

Comment: Thank you very much abarnert that explains eveything... Loved your way of explanation and help. Wish i could give you hundred likes..